# Запрос на сервер с помощью curl php

Tags: php, curl

Хей! Упорно, но безуспешно пытаюсь достучаться до сервера с помощью `curl`.
Хочу получить ответ но в итоге получаю сообщение о ошибки ключа api.

Вкратце, коннектиться пытаюсь по схеме как [тут](https://mercury.postlight.com/web-parser/)
если конкретно пытаюсь перевести этот запрос в php. Запрос делаю с сервера без ssl сертификата.

```
GET https://mercury.postlight.com/parser?url=https://trackchanges.postlight.com/building-awesome-cms-f034344d8ed
    Content-Type: application/json
    x-api-key: SWN6wongtJ6krFOa4MHwzRsAzHcaruPqGkrDqH8A
```

Делаю это вот таким образом:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://mercury.postlight.com/parser');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'x-api-key: ********************'
    ));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'url=http://www.velosite.ru/kak-vybrat-velosiped-dlja-vzroslogo/');
$out = curl_exec($curl);

echo $out;

curl_close($curl);
```

На что в ответ получаю:

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

Что нужно поменять? Я что то совсем не понимаю :(

Comment: [Я случайно создал две учетных записи, как их объединить?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 4):

Инициализируете вы cURL в переменную `$curl`:

```
$curl = curl_init();
```

А вот настройки передаете в переменную `$ch`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'x-api-key: ********************'
));
```

В этом, собственно, и ошибка.

---

Также я советую вам убрать заголовок `Content-Type: application/json` банально потому, что он вам не нужен, а также в параметр `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` передавать не query-строку, а массив:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('url' => 'http://www.velosite.ru/kak-vybrat-velosiped-dlja-vzroslogo/');
```

Если уж отправляете POST-запрос, то не забудьте задать параметр `CURLOPT_POST` равный `true`.